# Replacing elements in a list with the indices of a list containing all unique elements

Tags: python, list, replace, graph

Assume I have a list which contains the unique nodes `A`-`D` of a graph:

```
List1 = [A, B, C, D]
```

And another list, which contains the edges of a graph with pairs of the elements:

```
List2 = [[C, D], [B, A], [D, A], [C, B]]
```

How can I write a fast and economic way to replace all elements of `List2` with the indices of the elements in `List1`, so that I get:

```
List3 = [(2, 3), (1, 0), (3, 0), (2, 1)]
```

My current way of doing this is:

```
for i in range(len(List2)):
    List3[i] = (List1.index(List2[i][0]), List1.index(List2[i][1]))
```

However, this takes a really long time for a large list, and I was trying to find a potentially faster way to do this.

Comment: If you need to do it repeatedly, why not create a mapping e.g. `{A: 1, B: 2, ...}`, which can trivially be created with `enumerate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `dict` from your letters to the indices you want

```
>>> indices = {key: index for index, key in enumerate(List1)}
>>> indices
{'B': 1, 'D': 3, 'A': 0, 'C': 2}
```

Then use a nested list comprehension

```
>>> [[indices[i] for i in sub] for sub in List2]
[[2, 3], [1, 0], [3, 0], [2, 1]]
```

**Edit**
To get a list of tuple

```
>>> [tuple(indices[i] for i in sub) for sub in List2]
[(2, 3), (1, 0), (3, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: But this requires you to call `List1.index` for every sub-element in `List2`, which is hugely inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I will change it in my original post

Comment: So from google I have learned that using list comprehensions (as in how you are doing it) is faster than using a for loop (as in my original post). Is there also an alternative to the "index", as pointed out by jonrsharpe?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Alternatively, use `enumerate(List1, 1)` to use 1-based indexing, rather than `+1` later.

Comment: @jonrsharpe TIL `enumerate` can take a second parameter :) Teaches me to RTFM haha

Comment: Thank you for the quick help! I think this solved my problem, i will try it out now

Comment: @user4911943 Sure, just swap out `[]` with `tuple()` in the inner list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension and index method of list to achieve what you want.

```
List1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

List2 = [['C', 'D'], ['B', 'A'], ['D', 'A'], ['C', 'B']]

print [ (List1.index(item[0]),List1.index(item[1])) for item in List2]
```